# Как сделать, что бы checkbox отмечал встроенный текст? он теперь отмечает сам checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).on("click", ".input-checkbox", function () {

    var $this = $(this);

    if ($this.is(":checked")) {
        $this.parent().addClass("selected");
    } else {
        $this.parent().removeClass("selected");
    }
});

function getNewLineItem(inputText) {
    return '<div class="input-group">' +
        '<span class="input-group-addon">' +
        '<input class="input-checkbox" type="checkbox" >' +
        '</span>' +
        '<input class="input-check form-control" type="text" value="' + inputText + '">' +
        '<span class="input-remove input-group-addon">' +
        '<a href="#">X</a>' +
        '</span>' +
        '</div>';
}
```

Comment: Хм, а что такое "встроенный текст"? И что значит "теперь"? Раньше какая-то предыстория была? Что надо-то?

Answer (score 1):

Довольно сложно понять по этому описанию, но вот так нужно?

```js
$(function(){
  // По клику добавляем одно getNewLineItem() с случайным числом
  $('#addNewEntry').on('click', e => $('#wrapper').append(getNewLineItem(Math.random())));
  
  //
  $('#wrapper').on("click", ".input-checkbox", function () {
    var $this = $(this);

    if ($this.is(":checked")) { // Если отмечен
      // Добавляем класс предку
      $this.parent().addClass("selected");
      
      // Ищем текстовое поле и выделяем его содержимое
      $this.parent().parent().find('.form-control').get(0).select();
    }else{
      $this.parent().removeClass("selected");
    }
  });
});

function getNewLineItem(inputText){
  return '<div class="input-group">' +
    '<span class="input-group-addon">' +
    '<input class="input-checkbox" type="checkbox" >' +
    '</span>' +
    '<input class="input-check form-control" type="text" value="' + inputText + '">' +
    '<span class="input-remove input-group-addon">' +
    '<a href="#">X</a>' +
    '</span>' +
    '</div>';
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='wrapper'></div>
<hr />
<input type='button' id='addNewEntry' value='Add new entry' />
```